# Jquery Mobile remember if href is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to remember if a href has been clicked, on jquery mobile for dynamic href

When hrefs are generated in a loop with multiple parameter tagged on.

For example

```
      for (var j=0; j<total; j++) {
 var Url = "page.html?id="+ + encodeURIComponent(id);

 var $newContent ="<a href='"+Url+"'><div>ID='"+id+"'</div></a>"
}
```

And there are many of these hrefs are generated, but what can i tag on to allow me to distinguish if a specific id has been clicked?

Comment: there is :visited css sub property, i think it can solve your problem

Comment: Thanks i will check it out! Just a quick question, do you know if that would cache even when you close up the app? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function on the href, that sends the href that is pressed to the log file, and from that you can decode as to which tag is been clicked upon.

```
<a href="page.html?id=1" onclick=function_getVal(1)>
<a href="page.html?id=1" onclick=function_getVal(2)>
<a href="page.html?id=1" onclick=function_getVal(3)>
<script>
 function_getVal(id){
  alert(id);
 }
</script>
```

or call this function_getVal() in the url generator itself.